# Is this a fake pulse sensor?

Tags: sensors

A couple of days ago, I purchased a pulse sensor online for a project. Before actually doing anything with it, I wanted to capture and view its analogue waveform output. One while placing my finger on it and one when in the default state, so that I can see the trend or difference in the two waveforms. But when I captured the output, it seems like there is not much difference. Just some random noise I guess. Also, I checked the company website who may have made this one and it all looks good to me.

1. The image below shows the waveform captured when no finger is placed on the sensor.
   [image]
2. The image below shows the waveform captured when my index finger is placed on the sensor.
   [image]
3. This is my setup for the sensor for measuring pulses.
   [image]
4. This image shows the face of the sensor.
   [image]

I need some insights from folks here regarding this sensor. Is it showing some junk output? or my understanding is wrong and there's a better way to figure this out/ work with this sensor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in any way about Arduino, and because even for an SE site where the subject matter could be on topic, the question fails to state details of the measurement taken.

Comment: What is a pulse sensor? I don't see what this question has to do with Arduinos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second trace looks like a pulse to me. With that kind of sensor you don't get the PQRST traces of an ECG - just a slight bump when you get a pulse.

Comment: Ok, that means this sensor does work. I am connecting the output of this sensor to a 24 (~18 ENOB) bit ADC and getting the digital data. What would be the right approach to accurately capturing these bumps using the digital samples while being able to differentiate it from other junk?.

Comment: Low pass filter it to remove the random spikes, and then look for the change in signal level through a threshold, maybe with some hysteresis.

Comment: To design a low pass digital filter, I need to know the cut off frequency, how do I know that?

Comment: You don't need that level of detail. The difference in frequency between signal and noise is big enough that simple averaging of samples is enough.